# How to define sys props in pom.xml when running a file from within Netbeans using exec-maven-plugin:exec?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

When using Netbeans, running a file/class inside a Maven project means that Netbeans executes something like "mvn exec:exec ...".

Now I want to access the maven sys prop ${basedir} from within the executed class. How do I do that? Setting a command line in pom.xml overwrites the command line from Netbeans and therefore does not work. Using exec:java together with the exec-maven-plugin's sys props configuration section does not work either because I'm using a special class (re-)loader that only works with exec:exec (somehow project dependency classes cannot be found by it because the default loader seems to be different).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding -Dbasedir=${basedir} to the exec.args parameter works:

```
exec.args=-classpath %classpath -Dbasedir=${basedir} ${packageClassName}
```

Netbeans does not know about that variable, so it looks like the exec-maven-plugin evaluates that string.